# Wordpress Else statement not working in $comments loop

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, comments

For my WP-theme I am displaying comments for each blog-post. Everything works except my `else` statement, I figured this is because every `$post` counts ALL `$comments` on the page, instead of just its own.

So this is my php:

```
<?php 
    $args = array(
        'post_id' => $post->ID,
        'status' => 'approve'
    );
    $comments = get_comments($args); ?>

        if (get_comments_number($comments)==0) {
            wp_list_comments(array('per_page' => 10, // Allow comment pagination
            'reverse_top_level' => false //Show the latest comments at the top of the list ), $comments); 
            } else {
                echo "<i>No Comments</i>";
     } ?>
```

I tried with two different foreach statements, first with $comments:

```
<?php 
    foreach($comments as $comment) :
        if (get_comments_number($comments)==0) {
            wp_list_comments(array('per_page' => 10, // Allow comment pagination
            'reverse_top_level' => false //Show the latest comments at the top of the list ), $comments); 
            } else {
                echo "<i>Inga kommentarer än</i>";
     } ?>
  } endforeach; ?>
```

Using $posts:

```
<?php 
        foreach($posts as $post) :
            if (get_comments_number($comments)==0) {
                wp_list_comments(array('per_page' => 10, // Allow comment pagination
                'reverse_top_level' => false //Show the latest comments at the top of the list ), $comments); 
                } else {
                    echo "<i>Inga kommentarer än</i>";
         } ?>
      } endforeach; ?>
```

The second just rendered "This post is password protected. Enter the password to view comments." instead of `include('intranet-comments.php');` (which is called after the comments).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass postID as argument to `get_comments_number` instead of array of comments. Check [wp codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_comments_number).
And why are you trying to display comments when number of comments is 0 ?

Should look something like this: **NOT TESTED. Answered via Smartphone**

```
<?php 
$args = array(
    'post_id' => $post->ID,
    'status' => 'approve'
);
    if (get_comments_number($post->ID)!=0) {
          $comments = get_comments($args);
          // and do something with commenzs
        } else {
            echo "<i>No Comments</i>";
 } ?>
```